# onActivityResult only recognised as variable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, methods

While creating an onActivityResult method Eclipse is only recognising it as a variable for some un-announced reason.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int resultCode, int requestCode, Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Class_2.RESULT_CODE && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data.hasExtra("returnKey1")) {
            int number = number + getIntent().getExtras().getInt("returnKey1");
        }
    }
}
```

Over the "*onActivityResult*" it just gives me an error and the message "*void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult*" any ideas?

Comment: Please post the whole class.

Comment: What's with the semi-colons in the first line? Shouldn't they be commas? And I think you should have "super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);" as the first line after that.

Comment: the ";" was a mistake, I put them in when I was messing around with it and forgot to take them out.

Comment: @8BitSensei : make sure you are extending an activity or not? if yes then just type onActivity and press CTRL + SHIFT .

Comment: Yes, and I did the CTRL + SHIFT on the other Activities, it highlights them all but my onActivityResult, I can safely presume that eclipse isn't picking it up for some reason.

Comment: @8BitSensei : means you are not extending activity in your class where you are add onActivityResult method. this method only work in Activity context instead if any other like button or any view

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what else you have in your class but try changing

```
protected void onActivityResult(int resultCode; int requestCode; Intent data)
```

to

```
protected void onActivityResult(int resultCode, int requestCode, Intent data)
```

You should also include a call to:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: Correct but does not solve my problem, I'll update the question to show the current code, it still has the same error.

Answer (score 1):

put this into method

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: while this is correct, it is not in any manner an answer to the posted question, and thus it should be a comment but an answer.

Comment: Why ? it is the answer of question. Because of forgetting this line. Compiler throws that error. So this is answer , not comment !

Comment: I doubt that is the solution, only thing that line does is call another method. Not return anything, which is what the compiler (thinks) it should expect.

Comment: It is absolutely not the answer of his question. His question indicates that he cannot get his code to compile. Calling an additional routine is not going to change that. You correctly spotted an additional problem that he did not know he had, but you did not answer his question.

Answer (score 1):

use this template for Overriding `onActivityResult` of Activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int resultCode, int requestCode, Intent data)
{                   
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // do your work here
}
```

and remove semi-con `";"` from parameters of  `onActivityResult` and make sure you are overriding `onActivityResult` method inside your Activity class also

Answer (score 0):

Your method is declared incorrectly as you used semicolon `;` to separate its arguments, while it should be just colon `,`. So it should be:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int resultCode, int requestCode, Intent data)
```

instead of

```
protected void onActivityResult(int resultCode; int requestCode; Intent data)
```